# WPF set image position on grid (not row and column)

Tags: wpf

Is there any way in WPF to set X and Y coordinates of an image relative to it's parent grid?
Not using the setRow or setColumn, but X and Y.

Comment: You can try to use a Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what the Grid control is for, that's what Canvas does. What you can do is add a Canvas control that spans all rows and columns of the grid, and then use the Canvas.X and Canvas.Y attributes to set the position.

Comment: Thanks! and Is there a way to set the image position (x,y) relative to the WPF window?

Comment: the same - have a Canvas that spans the entire window (so not contained in the grid, but directly as a child of the window), and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Margin` property to create space around element.

`Margin` can be set in formats `"Left, Top, Right, Bottom"` (e.g. `Margin="10,20,10,20"`) or `"LeftAndRight,TopAndBottom"` (e.g. `Margin="10,20"`, equal to previous example) or just one value for all sides (e.g. `Margin="10"`). X and Y will be Left and Top.

Panels (Grid, StackPanel, etc) respect Margin settings.

XAML designer in Visual Studio uses `Margin`,`Width` and `Height` to locate elements in a fixed positions, when drag and drop controls from Toolbox ("nails" them to one place, not very nice for adaptive desing).

Using `Margin`,`Width` and `Height` together is similar to using `Location` and `Size` to position WinForms controls

Comment: so who was sitting on this question to downvote answer and question? do you have any better suggestions?